# Lubuntu not booting for install on Toshiba Satellite 2410

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Pls help me i am not able to install lubuntu 16.04 on Toshiba Satellite 2410 model.PS241L-5Y340P specs-Ram:1gb Processsor:Pentium 4 2.00ghz when ever select to boot from dvd it wont work but if i insert windows xp dvd its works pls assit me 
i want to keep the laptop because it has av out ,nice speakers and floppy reader.

Comment: Did you have a previous version that worked on that machine?

Comment: Try to install using usb flash. I had on old pc once that booted fine windows xp cd but no lubuntu (never solved it).

Comment: You select to boot from dvd and 'it wont work' - what type of 'wont work' do you mean? Do you get an error message? What does the error message say? Does it just not seem to be able to read the disk with no message given? I can make guesses for you but more information is needed. The Pentium M will need the 32-bit version. The 64-bit version won't work. There's also something that modern processors don't need to worry about called Physical Address Extension(PAE) . Do you get an error saying anything about PAE? Here's a link about PAE: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)

Comment: I downloaded 32 bit only but it didnt work so i downloaded zorin os it work but it was slow as snail.pls help me is there any other os that can work fast and G.U.I friendly and looks like ubuntu/windows/mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer is outdated but anyhow. I have an old Toshiba Satellite U200 PT300E and searching the web I found this link [http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/06/how-to-create-lubuntu-live-cd-or-usb.html](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/06/how-to-create-lubuntu-live-cd-or-usb.htmlhttp://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/06/how-to-create-lubuntu-live-cd-or-usb.html). I followed the step by step procedure described on it and I was able to burn a DVD and even could test Lubuntu 17.04 in my old Toshiba. I hope this helps other users.